# Way to call and explain: "potentially infinite set of attributes" in databases

Tags: data-structures, sets, database-theory

This is a bit of a theoretical question. I would like to know how to call the principle described below, in proper computer science terms, or math terms.

Let's say we have a database in which one entity is split into two tables: main and meta. The main table is a matrix where rows are instances (for instance each row is an order), columns are attributes (for instance order id, customer name). The meta table is a key-value store of other attributes where you'll see columns for the instance id, key, and value. Visual representation of this example below.

[image: Representation of the structure described above]

The thing about this structure is that it allows an instance to have an infinite number of properties, because any property of an 'order' just becomes a row in the 'meta' table.

So my question is: Is there a computer science term for 'potentially infinite set of properties'? I was thinking about 'indiscrete set', but I suspect this is not the correct way to describe this.

I am experimenting with this database structure, inspired by the Wordpress database. Also building a Laravel package that supports this structure: https://packagist.org/packages/phitech/entities. I personally think this is a practical data structure. But besides that, I feel I lack some knowledge and context to what I am actually doing. I'd like to learn this and also be able to describe it. That's why my question. This is not meant to be a discussion, which wouldn't be appropriate on SE. Just curious about your knowledge about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your "potentially infinite" (I would say: finite but unbounded) list of properties is known, depending on the programming language, as an *association list, property list, dictionary, associative array*, or *hash*. No doubt other terms are in use as well; I haven't used more than some 20-30 different languages. In mathematics, it is known as a *function* or *mapping* with a finite domain.

Your idea is known as EAV ([Entity-Attribute-Value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)).

It is [regarded with suspicion by relational database designers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios): use it if your set of attributes varies strongly at runtime, or if you aren't going to need to perform complex [querying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_language) on your data, but be aware of losing the advantages of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (value type checking, constraint checking).

Comment: also hashtable or hashmap